# jQuery vertical hover accordion

Tags: jquery, hover, accordion

What jQuery plugins exist for a vertical hover accordion? I am looking for a plugin to be used for a menu where:

- sub-menu items will only expand after a second being hovered over (so something that perhaps uses the hoverIntent plugin);
- it can degrade gracefully if Javascript is turned off; and
- will collapse/close any sub-menu item when the mouse moves completely off it.

thank u very much!

Comment: Like Ekeko said, jQuery UI is the way to go. But just a word of warning: This kind of accordion is f**ing annoying and makes me turn off JavaScript just for you...

Comment: I agree with you, but try convincing my client that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [jquery UI accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/). It has a lot of options and you can customize it, too.

Comment: thanx Ekeko, I'll look into it. I believe its the same one developed by "bassistance.de" I'll look into it more carefully and see how I can  tweak it

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I think there may be inherent problems with using a mouseover or mouseenter event to control a vertical accordion -- unless you *really* know what the submenus are going to be like.

The problem lies in the what-if: you have a long list of items in a submenu, and some short submenus or single menu items that follow below.  like this:

- menu

  - 1
  - 2

    - a
    - b
    - c
    - d
    - e
    - f
  - 3
  - 4
  - 5

    - a
    - b
    - c

So when you move from #2 to #3, #2 collapses, putting your pointer way down the list.  You fire all the mouseover/out or mouseenter/leave events for #3, #4, #5... and maybe move past the whole menu... things can start bouncing around like crazy.

Maybe the hoverIntent plugin can be made to work, but I think just using the mouse click is a more elegant solution.  At least for an abstracted list, that is.

Answer (score 1):

hey take a look to this plugin for Hover Accordion, i was looking for the same effect and I found this. http://berndmatzner.de/jquery/hoveraccordion/

And this may help to you to make hover with de original accordion of jquery.
`$("#accordion").accordion({
            event: "mouseover"
        });`

Comment: woah! cant believe this post is still active :) . I remember tryin this plugin, but had some problems with it - it was a long while back and I've unfortunately forgotten. I do remember that I stuck with the accordion plugin from Jörn Zaefferer and binded it to the hoverIntent function. I found that to work best. IMHO, I agree fully with Christian Studer's first comment in my original post at the top - these become usability nightmares, especially for novice users. If this is for navigation purposes, try looking at alternative ideas. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

- http://designreviver.com/tutorials/jquery-examples-horizontal-accordion/
- http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jQuery-common-accordion